# How to add exe of WPF app to Start->Programs

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, executable

I have created an exe of the WPF UI application, using Setup project in the VS 2008 application. I have generated exe's and msi's in DEBUG and RELEASE mode.

I am able to install the application too. But, how can I have the shortcut of it in Start-> Programs ??

Any option to be provided while creating exe in DEBUG r RELEASE mode?

Please guide me.
thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

Create a setup project in vs 2008 IDE. And it will ask you (in the first step) where to place your application by default (File system on your target machine). There you can choose Application folder, users desktop or Uers program menu.

if you wanted to place your app at program menu under the **XX App**, then you have to add a foilder **XX App** by right clicking the Uers program menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps on the your project.

1. Right click on the project and Select View-->File System

2. Select 'User's Programs Menu' from the left. Right click on it and Add-->Folder add give your Application name for the folder say 'MyAppln'.

3. Click on the Application Folder. Select the file you want to add in Start-->Programs say MyApp.exe.
Right Click and Create ShortCut. You will get a Shortcut there with name 'Shortcut to MyApp.exe'. Just rename it to 'MyApp'.

4. Cut the file from here.

5. Paste the shortcut file in the Folder 'MyAppln' in 'User's Programs Menu'.

Comment: its an old answer ( in 2009). so I assume you are taking about 2008 and  I am using VS 2012 so I can not see View --> File System. not sure how I can achieve the same in VS2012